# Assigning value from URL in Orbeon in Internet Explorer: polish characters encoding issue

Tags: orbeon

In Orbeon 4.5 I found following bug: when loading form in FormRunner and trying to assign value to input field from URL which contains polish characters, f.e 'Paweł', which is in UTF-8 'Pawe%C5%82', instead of actual characters there are '?'. For example:

```
 http://localhost:8081/orbeon/fr/SZPROT/MyTestingForm/new?firstname=Pawe%C5%82
```

[image]

This problem only occurs while using Internet Explorer. On Chrome etc. everything works fine. Is this a well-known problem? Maybe upgrading Orbeon to newer version could help?

Comment: Does your HTTP connector enable UTF-8 encoding explicitly, for example, with Tomcat: `<Connector URIEncoding="utf-8" ...>`?

Comment: Also, on which version of IE is this?

Comment: @ebruchez Yes, it does.

Comment: @avernet Internet Explorer 11

Comment: I am unable to reproduce this with 4.9. Here is what I see on IE11: http://screencast.com/t/Crlj05LFxR. And here is the source of the form you can paste in Form Builder to test this: https://gist.github.com/avernet/a5af3f6c1274e623db83. Would you be able to check if you're still having this problem with 4.9?

Comment: Problem solved - it had nothing to do with loading data from URL, it turned out to be a proxy issue. Thanks